# Python, for loop for to break repetition

Tags: python, for-loop, repeat

Let's say I have stuff which repeats but only one number changes. How can I make this in one for-loop for example?

As you see in this example (which goes down to pic13), it uses variables and qt names like `self.hand_pos1`.

```
pic0 = os.path.join(path, 'tiles', '%s.png' % player_hand[0])
self.hand_pos0.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(pic0))
pic1 = os.path.join(path, 'tiles', '%s.png' % player_hand[1])
self.hand_pos1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(pic1))
pic2 = os.path.join(path, 'tiles', '%s.png' % player_hand[2])
self.hand_pos2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(pic2))
pic3 = os.path.join(path, 'tiles', '%s.png' % player_hand[3])
self.hand_pos3.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(pic3))
pic4 = os.path.join(path, 'tiles', '%s.png' % player_hand[4])
self.hand_pos4.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(pic4))
pic5 = os.path.join(path, 'tiles', '%s.png' % player_hand[5])
self.hand_pos5.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(pic5))
```

Comment: You might want to try an enumerated list

Comment: Why do you have things like `hand_pos<n>` and `pic<n>` instead of using lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate, then access the elements of your array. To access attributes with dynamic names, you can use `getattr`.

```
for elem in range(14):
    pic = os.path.join(path, 'tiles', '{}.png'.format(player_hand[elem]))
    getattr(self, "hand_pos{}".format(elem)).setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(pic))
```

But consider replacing the `self.hand_posX` attributes with a list or dict.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having `self.hand_pos0`, `self.hand_pos1`, etc. collect them all into a list. Then you can do:

```
for position, hand in zip(self.hand_pos, player_hand):
    pic = os.path.join(path, 'tiles', '%s.png', % hand)
    position.setPixMap(QtGui.QPixmap(pic)
```